# How can I create iterative scalable arguments in a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p>JavaScript can change HTML attribute values.</p>

<p>In this case JavaScript changes the value of the src (source) attribute of an image.</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('bulb0').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="bulb0" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:50px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('bulb0').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

<p></p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('bulb1').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="bulb1" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:50px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('bulb1').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

<p></p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('bulb2').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="bulb2" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:50px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('bulb2').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

<p></p>

<button onclick = turnOn()>Turn All lights ON</button>

<button onclick = turnOff()>Turn All lights OFF</button>

<button onclick = turnRandomOn()>Turn Any light ON</button>

<script>
    function turnOn() {
        document.getElementById('bulb0').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
        document.getElementById('bulb1').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
        document.getElementById('bulb2').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
        console.log('All lights were turned on');
    }
    function turnOff() {
        document.getElementById('bulb0').src='pic_bulboff.gif';
        document.getElementById('bulb1').src='pic_bulboff.gif';
        document.getElementById('bulb2').src='pic_bulboff.gif';
        console.log('All lights were turned off');
    }
    function turnRandomOn() {
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);  
        console.log(random);
        turnOff();
        if (random == 0) {
            document.getElementById('bulb0').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
            } else 
        if (random == 1) {
            document.getElementById('bulb1').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
            } else
        if (random == 2) {
            document.getElementById('bulb2').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
            }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello there! I'm on my first steps learning JS. I practiced with an interesting self-invented exercise that I just finished, the task consist in creating N-lamps that you can switch On/Off with a button for each lamp, I also added the idea of turning all on/off with just one button and the same for setting on/off a random lamp.
The code I shared works fine but I know is not scalable at all since I had to put the lamps by hand. My question is the following:

How can I improve this code to select an HTML element defined by a recursive variable? What I'm trying to say is, for example, instead having a line with the object `"document.getElementById('bulb0')"`, how could I change it for something like `"document.getElementById('bulbN')"`(where N is variable).

I know it is with an iterative loop but every time I try defining the argument it throws me an error. I tried these two ways:

1. `getElementById('"' + bulb + N + '"').innerHTML`
2. Defining the argument `('"' + bulb + N + '"')` as a separated variable and later adding it with the same procedure

I will truly appreciate your help, even more if you can share the code

PS: The exercise can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using `template literal strings.`

```
function turnOn() {

    for(let i of [0,1,2]) {
    document.getElementById(`bulb${i}`).src='pic_bulbon.gif';
    } 
    console.log('All lights were turned on');

}

function turnOff() {

    for(let i of [0,1,2]) {
    document.getElementById(`bulb${i}`).src='pic_bulboff.gif';
    } 
    console.log('All lights were turned off');

}
```

##### Now, what you are doing wrong?

```
getElementById('"' + bulb + N + '"').innerHTML

// '"' + bulb + N + '"' -> bulb is taken as variable, not like string.
// instead of this you can just use "bulb" + N
```

```
getElementById("bulb" + N).innerHTML
```

e.g.

```js
let N = 0
console.log("bulb" + N)


// now here, bulb is taken as a variable
// this will give you an error. because bulb variable is not defined
// console.log('"' + bulb + N + '"') throw an error


// if you define bulb variable,
{
const bulb = 'bulb'
console.log('"' + bulb + N + '"')
console.log(bulb + N)
// you can see '"' + bulb + N + '"' !== bulb + N
}
```

if you need to know more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you so much!
That's the answer I was looking for, I knew there was a way but I didn't know how to put it in code. I'll try again my exercise with this

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques you can use which I've commented on in the code but I'll mention here with some links to the documentation.

1. Use a loop as you suggested to build some HTML using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Push each string into an array, and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array into one string and add it to the element that contains the lamps: `lampsContainer`.
2. Attach [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the `lampsContainer`, and the buttons. When they're clicked they'll call a handler. With regards to `lampsContainer` we're using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - attaching one listener to a container that catches events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.
3. If the `lampsContainer` is clicked we first check to see if the element that we clicked on is a button, and then we get that button's lamp element using [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling). We [toggle the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) on that lamp on/off.
4. The other buttons, as mentioned, have their own handlers. They either turn off (remove the `on` class) or turn on (add the `on` class) on all of the lamps. The random button simply toggles one random lamp from the lamp node list on/off.

```js
// Initialise the lamp number,
// and an array to store the HTML string
const n = 4;
const html = [];

// Using a template string create a series of
// sections each containing a button, and a "lamp"
// element. Push each string into the array
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  const str = `
    <section class="lampContainer">
      <div class="lamp"></div>
      <button>lamp${i + 1}</button>
    </section>
  `;
  html.push(str);
}

// Cache the elements for the lamps container,
// and the other buttons
const lampsContainer = document.querySelector('.lampsContainer');
const toggleAllOn = document.querySelector('.toggleAllOn');
const toggleAllOff = document.querySelector('.toggleAllOff');
const random = document.querySelector('.random');

// Add the HTML string to the lampsContainer element
lampsContainer.innerHTML = html.join('');

// Add some listeners to the lamps container, and the buttons
lampsContainer.addEventListener('click', handleLamps);
toggleAllOn.addEventListener('click', handleToggleAllOn);
toggleAllOff.addEventListener('click', handleToggleAllOff);
random.addEventListener('click', handleRandom);

// When an element in the lamps container is clicked
// check that it was a button, and then find its lamp
// element. Toggle the lamp `on` class.
function handleLamps(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    const lamp = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    lamp.classList.toggle('on');
  }
}

// Find all the lamps in the lamps container,
// and add an `on` class
function handleToggleAllOn() {
  const lamps = lampsContainer.querySelectorAll('.lamp');
  lamps.forEach(lamp => lamp.classList.add('on'));
}

// Find all the lamps in the lamps container,
// and add an `on` class
function handleToggleAllOff() {
  const lamps = lampsContainer.querySelectorAll('.lamp');
  lamps.forEach(lamp => lamp.classList.remove('on'));
}

// Find all the lamps in the lamps container,
// find a random lamp from that node list,
// and toggle its `on` class
function handleRandom() {
  const lamps = lampsContainer.querySelectorAll('.lamp');
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * lamps.length);
  lamps[rnd].classList.toggle('on');
}
```

```css
.lampContainer { display: flex; flex-direction: row; width:20%; align-items: center; }
.lamp { margin: 0.25em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white; }
.on { background-color: yellow; }
button, .lamp { border-radius: 5px; }
button { text-transform: uppercase; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: lightgreen; }
.buttonsContainer { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<section class="lampsContainer"></section>
<section class="buttonsContainer">
  <button class="toggleAllOn">Toggle all on</button>
  <button class="toggleAllOff">Toggle all off</button>
  <button class="random">Toggle random on/off</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

- Use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create element with any iterator
- Then assign attributes. Then simply add that to DOM
- Extending it further you can even customize each element while creation base on your conditions